# Select last 10 records for every team

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm working with a table that contains some statistics about historical football games, the table looks (simplified) like this:

```
game_id   game_date   home_team   away_team   home_goal   away_goal
1         01/01/2001  A           B           0           1
2         01/01/2001  C           D           2           0
3         01/02/2001  A           C           1           0
4         01/02/2001  B           D           0           1
5         01/03/2001  D           A           3           4
6         01/03/2001  C           B           1           2
```

Now I want to select the last 10 games (by date) played by every team (with no difference if they're played at home or away). The result (for the last 2 games) should look something like this:

```
game_id   game_date   home_team   away_team   home_goal   away_goal
5         01/03/2001  D           A           3           4
6         01/03/2001  C           B           1           2
3         01/02/2001  A           C           1           0
4         01/02/2001  B           D           0           1
```

This is the query I have for one single team (team A):

```
SELECT * FROM game_table
WHERE home_team = A
OR away_team = A
ORDER BY game_date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Is it possible to generalize this query to get the result for all the teams in the table?

Comment: Your question is tagged "sql-server", but you are using `limit`.  SQL Server does not support `limit`.  Also, your sample results don't make sense.  Why does "D" only show up once?  There are 4 teams, so I would be expecting 8 records (if all teams played two games).

Comment: I will be moving everything on sql-server, but at the moment I was testing everything out on a local db on my computer (postgre). Everything else I'm doing is fairly simple so I wasn't worried about differences between various dbms, as all the sql sintax I'm using elsewhere is quite standard.
Every team has 3 opponents, therefore appears 3 times, D (and B) just happens to play two games away and only one at home, but it indeed shows up 3 times overall.

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume you have a table of teams.  In this case, I think `apply` is the simplest method:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM teams t CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (10) g.*
      FROM game_table g
      WHERE t.team IN (g.home_team, g.away_team)
      ORDER BY game_date DESC
     ) g
ORDER BY t.team;
```